# In TCP/IP sockets, how would the server know that a client is busy and not receiving data ?

Tags: sockets, unix, networking, tcp, ip

In TCP/IP sockets, how would the server know that a client is busy and not receiving data ?

My solution:

Use connect(),

I am not sure.

thanks

Comment: You need to define "busy". In general if the client process is not reading data from the socket then eventually the write(2) call on the server will block. Here "eventually" is controlled by window/buffer sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In TCP/IP sockets, how would the server know that a client is busy and
>   not receiving data

If a TCP is constantly pushing data that the peer doesn't acknowledge, eventually the send window will fill up. At that point the TCP is going to buffer data to "send later". Eventually   the buffer size will be reached and **`send(2)` will hang** (something it doesn't usually do).

**If `send(2)` starts hanging it means the peer TCP isn't acknowledging data**.

Obviously, even if the peer TCP accepts data it doesn't mean the peer application actually uses it. You could implement your own `ACK` mechanism on top of `TCP`, and it's not as unreasonable as it sounds. It would involve having the client send a "send me more" message once in a while.

Comment: Or, if you enable non-blocking i/o on the socket descriptor, send/write will fail with errno being EWOULDBLOCK

Comment: +1 Pretty much exactly what I was trying to say, but much more technically oriented.

Comment: @nos, what is meaning of EWOULDBLOCK ? I am a beginner.

Comment: @user1002288 If you use non blocking sockets, instead of hanging `send` will return `-1` and will set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`. Read [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html)

Comment: @cnicutar, chris,  what kinds of error numbers will be returned from send() if buffer overflows ?

Comment: @user1002288: either it will block (sleep) until it can send something, or if you are using a non-blocking socket it will return -1 with errno set to EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN.

Answer (score 1):

A client will almost always receive your data, by which I mean the OS will accept the packets and queue them up for reading. If that queue fills up, then the sender will block (TCP, anyways). You can't actually know the activity of the client code. Pretty much your only option is to use timeouts.

Comment: how to use timeouts ?  set up a timer ? but, before sending out data, how does the sender know the data transmission time ?

Comment: No, many blocking calls support timeouts. And knowing the transmission time is neither here nor there. The timer starts as soon as the call starts blocking.